# Average of second element of tuples in a list

Tags: visual-studio, recursion, f#, pattern-matching, tuples

I'm new to F#, so sorry if this sounds too basic. 
I'm trying to calculate the average of second elements of a list of tuples using recursion and pattern matching but it's not giving me correct result. The code i have :

```
let rec getAverageAge (list: List<string*int>) =
      let listSize = float 1 / float list.Length
      match list with
        | [] -> 0.0
        | head :: tail -> ( float (2016 - snd head) * listSize  + getAverageAge tail )
```

I'm calling it like this :

```
getAverageAge [("A",2015); ("B",2015); ("C",2015)]
```

If i only do the sum , it works. But when i incorporate the division required for calculating the average age the result is not right. Like in this case average should be 1(average age not the average of all the numbers) but it's giving me 1.83333. What am i doing wrong? I guess something's wrong with float division. Any insight will help.

Comment: @pascalbetz whoops, sorry. Learning multiple languages at the same time is certainly not a good idea. Edited my post. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: You're dividing by list size on every iteration, not once at the end.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`listSize` is being multiplied into the result on every iteration in the recursive function, so that the iterations sum up to: 1/3 + 1/2 + 1 = 1.8333(...)

To convert the integers in the tuples to float and get the average, you could use `List.averageBy`:

```
[ ("A", 2015); ("B", 2015); ("C", 2015) ]
|> List.averageBy (fun (_, year) -> float (2016 - year))
```